# POST url 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: javascript, jquery, csrf, internal-server-error

I'm having issues in running a ajax on a webserver.
Whenever I try to run the program on Visual Studio, it works perfectly fine with the localhost. But comes up with POST  500 (Internal Server Error)

I've had a look online what can solve this issue and I've tried adding a meta tag containing a csrf token. But still didn't work.

Here is the error that's coming up:
[POST Internal Server Error 500 Screenshoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOBps.png)

```js
    if (m) {
        // generate the image data
        var image_NEW = document.getElementById("canvas").toDataURL("image/jpeg");
        image_NEW = image_NEW.replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '');

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'Default.aspx/SaveImage',
            data: '{ "imageData" : "' + image_NEW + '" }',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (msg) {
                alert('Image saved to your root Folder !');
            }
        });
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does your server error log have any useful information? This isn't a problem with your JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

**500:internal server error** clearly means you have some error on server side code.In your case check for error(s) in you r **c#** code.
Click on the error link in the console window to get details of the error

Comment: Thanks for the reply geekbro. From the screenshot, it doesn't seem it is coming from my c# code. It looks like it's having errors on the jquery. Could you please help me solve this. Cheers.

Comment: Yes you can clearly see the URL in the error..it's the same URL you are posting you data from JavaScript..what happens when you click that error link?

Comment: Open up network tab in the console window,clear it..then click on the button that fires this function..then in the network you will see the error..then in the network tab only click on the error link.you can see the details..I would prefer using google chrome..good luck